# Cassandra/Solr data model improvement

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE videos_tags (
  id text,
  tag text,
  video text,
  someotherfield long,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 1296000
AND compaction={'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

The table stores a list of tags and videos. A video can have one or more tags; and a tag can be attributed to more than one video. Example:

```
id  | tag         | video
------------------------------------------
1   | dancing     | video1
2   | singing     | video2
3   | prank       | video3
4   | prank       | video4
5   | funny       | video3
6   | cover       | video2
```

I want to show to my users a list of related videos based from tag assignment - the more tags a certain video has in common with the user's video, the more "related" it is. The actual approach that I use comprises of 2 steps:

1. Get a list of the user's video's tags

   q=*:*&fq=video:video1&fl=tag
2. Identify the videos use the same tags as the user's video and select the top 10  (resultset slicing is done in application side)

   q=*:*&fq=tag:tag1 AND tag:tag2 AND tag:tag3 AND !video:video1&fl=video&stats=true&stats.field=someotherfield&stats.facet=video

   Note: I used stats instead of plain facet because I also need the sum of *someotherfield*

This approach yields an average execution time of 30 seconds. Unfortunately, the maximum acceptable query time for my app is 10 seconds

Is there a better approach to tackling this data requirement? I'm open to:

1. Alternative query approach (minor tweaks are preferred; but I can accept something as drastic as replacing my 2-step approach completely)
2. Alternative schema

Notes:

1. The actual schema has several other fields that I removed from this post for brevity
2. I do all read operations via Solr (Datastax Enterprise 4.6.0). Nothing fancy in the Solr schema
3. The table currently holds 1.5 billion rows, but could grow to double or triple of that within years (so the solution must take into account the table/index size)
4. No fulltext search - only exact string filters

Comment: Are the cluster nodes compute or I/O-bound during that 30 seconds?

Comment: What's a good way to know that? (preferably in an automated manner while I run my app). I looked at the output of htop - out of 6 nodes, 2 have 101% cpu, 1 has 46% cpu, and 3 have 1 - 2% cpu during the 85-second runtime (yes, the runtime sometimes goes beyond the average 30). Memory is 90% in all nodes because  this particular function requires a very big heap (70gb out of 128gb physical ram per node). Anything smaller than that can lead to OOM

Comment: Did you consider [MoreLikeThisComponent](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) ?

Comment: @notdang can you enlighten me how to use in my case? Looking at the documentation, it seems that the component is mainly intended for document-based indexes (e.g. index  built from the contents of a collection of PDFs, DOCXs). My data, on the other hand, is a database table. When I did `mlt?q=id:1&rows=10&mlt.fl=tag`, all that I got is one result and that is the record with ID 1